# Spivak 4-23 How to construct the $k$-cell?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I'm going through Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, and I'm trying to do question 4-23 because I'm trying to understand how the chains and geometry works, but I'm having some trouble since most mark schemes cut off before this point.  The question is

> For $R>0$ and $n$ an integer, define a singular $1$-cube $c_{R,n}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2-0$ by $c_{R,n}(t)=(R\cos2\pi nt,R\sin2\pi nt)$.  Show that there isa singular $2$-cube $c:[0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2-0$ s.t. $c_{R_1,n}-c_{R_2,n}=\partial c$

I've been visualising $c_{R,n}$ as some phasor, and I've been working backwards, so I'm trying to construct a function in $[0,1]^2$ s.t. when $y=0$, $f(x,0)=(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}nx\right),\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}nx\right))$.  I think
$$f(x,y)=(R_1-R_2)\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}nx\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n(1+y)\right),\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}nx\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n(1+y)\right)\right)$$
works, but I'm not sure whether I've done it correctly, since in my case surely this could've been done with a single $c_{R,n}$?  I feel as though I'm completely missed the point of the exercise.  In the words of Pauli, it seems that "it's not even wrong"!

Comment: It’s *very* wrong for many reasons. When $n=1$, the singular $1$-cube wraps once around a circle of radius $R$. What geometric object fills it in? What fills in $c_{R,1}-c_{r,1}$? Describe the shapes and *then* try to write analytical formulas for $c$ that make sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin so I think this might be an issue with my understanding, I've been picturing this as a bunch of arrows in space, and by walking around the square with sides one and the lower left corner at the origin we see a full rotation of the vector.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @TedShifrin I also just noticed a massive typo, the second term should be $(1+y)$ if that changes anything.

Comment: Complementing Ted's comment, I'd think of $c_{R,n}$ as a _parametrized curve_ (i.e., as a circle for $n = 1$), not as a set of arrows (vector field?). <> In an encouraging sense, when you write down such a $2$-cube it should be almost _by inspection_.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang As in $c$ is an annulus?  It seemed to me from definition that $I$ mapped from some "parameter space" to the "domain space" of the function $c$, which itself would have a separate image space.  I've been visualising it as a vector field because I could think of moving along the axes as moving along the "parameter space".

Comment: Yes, the image of $c$ is an annulus. :) The two $1$-chains will be restrictions of $c$ to two opposite sides of the unit square.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang so would the form of $c(x,y)$ be $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ where $R_1<x<R_2$?

Comment: That formula is real-valued. :) <> Let's imagine writing $c(s, t) = (x, y)$. It suffices to arrange $c(1, t) = c_{R_{1}, n}(t)$ and $c(0, t) = c_{R_{2}, n}(t)$, and that $c(s, 0) = c(s, 1)$ for all $s$. <> If that seems unapparent, sketch the ("solid") unit square in the $(s, t)$-plane and consider what will happen when we trace its boundary counterclockwise under the stated conditions.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think I know what the solution is, and I think I've also figured out what I don't understand.  My mistake was trying to parameterise the entire boundary of the unit square in $(t,s)$-space, when here it seems only the two parallel sides form the boundary.  However, how can I know if the boundary is just two parallel sides and when is it all four sides of the unit square?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang and also just to check, is the solution $R_1(\cos(n\pi t),\sin(n\pi t))+(R_2-R_1)s(\cos(n\pi t),\sin(n\pi t))$?

Comment: 1. The boundary _is_ all four sides of the square, traced counterclockwise. :) 2. We can check whether this works by restricting to each of the four sides of the square, traced in the appropriate direction. 3. (Spoiler) That formula (well, with $2\pi nt$ inside the trig functions) is what I would have written. The two sides $t = 0$ and $t = 1$ cancel as chains. If you write an answer I'll upvote.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang in regards to 1, isn't the question written w.r.t. the boundary though (as in the RHS is $\partial c$, which to me implies the boundary of the entire square)?  So shouldn't $c_{R_1,n}-c_{R_2,n}$ have been the path parameterised from 0 to 1 counterclockwise around all four sides of the square?  I think I can type out the solution once I've figured this out.

Comment: Note that, naively, the boundary of the square is _four edges, each parametrized on_ $[0, 1]$. That is, the boundary is a singular chain (formal linear combination of singular cubes), not one single cube/path. <> Your (lightly rearranged/corrected) formula is$$c(s, t) = (R_2+(R_1-R_2)s)(\cos(2\pi nt), \sin(2\pi nt)).$$The boundary as a chain may be viewed as $c(s,0) + c(1,t) - c(s, 1) - c(0, t)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I was typing up an answer, when I thought of a case where $c_{R_1,n}(t)=c(t,0)+c(1,t)$, and $c_{R_2,n}(t)=c(t,1)+c(0,t)$.  I'm having some trouble disproving this as a possibility, or that it is a possibility.  Might you have some insight as to why this might/might not work?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang could the explanation for my previous question be as simple as $c_{R_1,n}$ and $c_{R_2,n}$ do not start and end at the same point?

Comment: 0. We do really want $c$ to depend on two variables. 1. The proposed formula (the "$(R_1-R_2)$..." formula in the answer) doesn't restrict to either $1$-chain on the boundary of the square. 2. We don't need to rule out your possibility two comments up; in fact, we probably _can_ arrange that two sides of the square map to each circle if we contort ourselves. But that would be a lot of work to make our lives difficult. 3. There's a crucial "$s$" missing in the last formula of the answer. 4. Have you made a sketch? :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not that since in the definition
$$\partial I^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{\alpha=0,1}(-1)^{i+\alpha}I^n_{(i,\alpha)}$$
if we fill in what it is a function of
$$\partial I^n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{\alpha=0,1}(-1)^{i+\alpha}I^n_{(i,\alpha)}(t)$$
we can see that travelling the path around the perimeter can be intuited as simultaneously travelling across each component.  If we first consider $t=0$, we can see that the boundary is given by two points $R_1(\cos(2\pi n\times0),\sin(2\pi n\times0))$ and $R_2(\cos(2\pi n\times0),\sin(2\pi n\times0))$.  We can consider these points as the boundary of $c(0,s)$.  Since at $t=1$ we can see that these two bounds are the same, and so we can say that $c(0,s)=c(1,s)$, which would mean the $s$ terms cancel out for each given $t$.  Thus, we can write
$$\begin{align*}
R_1(\cos(2\pi nt),\sin(2\pi nt))&=c(1,t)\\
R_2(\cos(2\pi nt),\sin(2\pi nt))&=c(0,t)
\end{align*}$$
Since $c(0,s)$ has to go from $R_2$ to $R_1$ as $s$ increases from $0$ to $1$, we have our solution
$$c(s,t)=[R_2+(R_1-R_2)s](\cos(2\pi nt),\sin(2\pi nt))$$

Comment: I think you're close! If you're not entirely happy with the final formula, maybe set $n = 1$ and carefully sketch the images of the four oriented sides of the square, which are ordinary parametrized plane curves. _Then_ see how the boundary formulas (the double sums at the top) reduce in the case of the unit square, and how this agrees with the sketch. (Note also: The "$n$" in the boundary formula is _dimension_ of the chain, which here is $2$. The problem statement also contains an "$n$", but that's a different $n$, representing a "winding number" of the $2$-chain, or of its boundary.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I was wondering actually, could an argument be made that since if we let $c_{R_1,n}=c(t,0)+c(1,t)$ this would require $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ to be doubly valued, which would contradict with $c$ being a function?  I can see the solution I do have is correct, but since I don't think the boundary has to be unique I was just trying to find a $c$ which would fit the naive guess.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, would you be open to a chat on StackEx (or any other platform) on the weekend?  I feel like while I do understand the concept a bit better, there are still some things I don't understand (i.e. I wouldn't feel comfortable explaining this concept to someone else)

Comment: Not available to chat in real-time, but hoping the posted diagram helps conceptually!

Answer (score 0):

In the hope the diagram for $n = 1$ is worth a thousand words, here are the standard $2$-cube in the $(s, t)$-plane with its oriented boundary, and its image under the mapping you've found. The key points are:

- The bottom and top edges cancel as $1$-chains, because they trace the same curve with opposite orientations.
- The orientations on the vertical sides of the unit cube cause the image circles to be traced in opposite directions; at the level of chains that amounts to subtracting the inner circle from the outer.

[image: A 2-chain whose boundary is a difference of circles]